# How to use functions from configuration file in python?

Tags: python-3.x, yaml

I have a yaml config file which looks like the following :

```
---

tables:

  - table: my_table
    db: my_user
    checks:
      - type: my_check
        column: [col1, col2, col3, col4, col5]
```

I am reading this config file and running checks based on **checks** section in yaml.

let's say I have a class which looks like the following :

```
class MasterCheck(object):

    def my_check(self, over_view_table, columns, label):
        if columns is None:
            null_check = set(over_view_table[(over_view_table['null_share'] > 0) | (
                over_view_table['empty_string_share'] > 0)].column_)
        else:
            null_check = set(over_view_table[(over_view_table['null_share'] > 0) | (
                over_view_table['empty_string_share'] > 0)].column_).intersection(set(columns))
        if len(null_check) > 0:
            self.alert = '{0}: NULLs in {1}'.format(label, null_check)
        else:
            self.alert = ""
```

I am able to run this check using the following method :

```
my_check = checks['type'][0]['type']
getattr(MasterCheck(), my_check)(table_summary, column, table)
```

The idea is to run the checks automatically based on what is specified in the configuration file. However there can be multiple checks supplied from configuration file for each table and I don't know in advance wether the string in the config file is an attribute of the class. Is there any recommended way where I can instantiate my checks from config file without knowing to which class this attribute belongs to. Any ideas in this regard would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your config file says:

> ```
>   - type: my_check
> ```

1. You could choose to have it explicitly say "type: MasterCheck.my_check" instead.
2. You could create a list of classes (or instantiated objects), and run a `getattr` search loop over all of them until you find `my_check`.
3. You could do the same thing with a mix-in pattern, where `MasterCheck` inherits from several classes, each of them contributing uniquely named functions.

For example:

```
class MasterCheck(NullCheck, FkCheck, SpellCheck):
```

where each of those classes offers one or more functions, like `my_check`,
that can appear in your config file.
(If you don't keep function names unique across classes,
then python's mro, Method Resolution Order, will pick a winner.)